# quantity + - in three different views with quantity to change in each view

Tags: swift, cart, product-quantity

I can't update the quantities between three different views,
I have the main page with the + and - keys and the quantity, the product viewer page also there with the + and - keys and the quantity, if I click on the more you insert the item in the cart always with the + - signs and the quantity, if I change the quantity on the first page it also updates the other two, while if I update it from the others it doesn't change the one on the first page, can you help me solve this? A thousand thanks

PRODUCT

```
struct Product: Identifiable,Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var categoria: ProductType
    var codice: String
    var descrizione: String = ""
    var prezzo: String
    var immagine: String = ""
    var quantita: Int = 0
}
```

SHAREDATA

```
    class SharedDataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cartProducts: [Product] = []
    
    func addToCart(product: Product) {
        cartProducts = cartProducts.filter {$0.id != product.id }
        cartProducts.append(product)
```

HOME

```
    struct Home: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    @StateObject var homeData: HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
    
                Button (action: {
                    sharedData.addToCart(product: product)
                    if product.quantita > 0 {
                        product.quantita -= 1
                    }
                } , label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus")
                })
                Text("\(product.quantita)")
    
                Button(action: {
                    sharedData.addToCart(product: product)
                    product.quantita += 1
                } , label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
```

PRODUCT DETAIL, IT UPDATES THE VIEW CORRECTLY IF I CHANGE FROM HOME, BUT IF I CHANGE FROM HERE IT DOESN'T UPDATE THE QUANTITY IN THE HOME

```
    struct ProductDetailView: View {
    @State var product: Product
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    
    var body: some View {
                        Button {
                            sharedData.addToCart(product: product)
                            if product.quantita > 0 {
                                product.quantita -= 1
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "minus")
                        }
    
                        Text("\(product.quantita)")
                        
                        Button {
                            sharedData.addToCart(product: product)
                                product.quantita += 1
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
```

CART PAGE IT UPDATES THE QUANTITY BUT NOT CORRECTLY, ONE WRONG, PLUS IF I INCREASE AND DECREASE THE QUANTITY FROM HERE IT DOESN'T UPDATE IT IN HOME NOR IN PRODUCT DETAILS

```
    struct CartPage: View { 
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    var body: some View{
                    Button {
                    if product.quantita > 0 {
                        product.quantita -= 1
                    }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "minus")
                    }
                    Text("\(product.quantita)")
                    Button {
                        product.quantita += 1
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
```

I'm a newbie and I can't update the quantity correctly between the three views, I need your help, thanks

Comment: In `SharedDataModel` you could try `func addToCart(product: Product) {
 if !cartProducts.contains(where: {$0.id == product.id}) { cartProducts.append(product) }
}`

Comment: so it adds only one item to the cart, I should increase the quantity in each view so that it updates it on all views, so if I click twice more on the main page I see two pieces in the product detail and in the cart, no I can do this, if I try to increase the quantity via the addToCart button with "product.quantita += 1" it tells me that it is a let and it is not mutable, thank you very much for the answer in the meantime!